# MongoDB not connecting to database in azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, azure, express

im trying to connect my express application to mongoDB and it works fine when I host the express application locally however when I upload it to Azure App Service it crashes.

What I've tried so far -
-Replacing the connection string with an environmental variable
-Removing the connection code entirely to identify exactly where the error occurs

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const workoutRoutes = require('./routes/workouts')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Connect to mongoose server
//------------------------------------------------- ERROR CAUSED BY THIS BLOCK OF CONNECTION CODE

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI).then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to the mongo databse database');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})

//------------------------------------------------- ERROR CAUSED BY THIS BLOCK OF CONNECTION CODE


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
//app.use('/api/workouts', workoutRoutes)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

[Application settings in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNpD4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've managed to work out the issue. It's with the mongoose version. I was using v6 so I downgraded to v5.11.10 and it worked perfectly. I don't know the exact part of mongoose v6 that is causing the issue but I've found a workaround for now.